# Make images in bootstrap carousel responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a carrousel with the bootstrap, but I can not make the images responsive. The problem is the images that have a height well greater than the width? I tested another image with a larger width and the image is distorted.

```css
body {
 padding-top: 68px !important;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Teste</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="#" alt="Logo">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link pr-5 nav-active" href="#">TESTE</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link pr-5" href="#">TESTE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <header class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div id="carouselBanner" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <a href="top-movie.html"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/rPdtLWNsZmAtoZl9PK7S2wE3qiS.jpg" alt="Fight Club"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/yE5d3BUhE8hCnkMUJOo1QDoOGNz.jpg" alt="House">
          </div>
        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselBanner" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" ></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselBanner" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>
    
    
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The carousel takes the whole height of the image, I tried to decrease the height, but the images are distorted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put some styling on your css,

```
<style>
    body {
    padding-top: 68px !important;
    background-color: black;
}

.carousel-inner {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}


.img {

     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed !important;
     background-size: cover !important;   
     background-position: center !important;
    }

      </style>
```

It scales down, when I minimize it

Comment: This way the image is cut, and I did not want the carousel to occupy the entire screen, I wanted to see some of the items that will be underneath it when it opens the site. Any other suggestions?